# Rails test DB constantly losing my PostgreSQL functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

My project uses a few custom PostgreSQL stored functions for some features that would be a pain in raw SQL or ActiveRecord. Every now and then I will run the RSpec test suite, and find that all my stored functions have been blown away. **Re-running the migrations to create them fixes the problem, but "rake db:structure:load" does NOT.**

I am deeply confused. I never drop either the dev or test database unless this happens, but my functions are like Schrodinger's PL/pgSQL. I am REALLY hoping this never happens in production.

Here is an example of a failing test and my attempts to fix it:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function round_half_down(numeric) does not exist

# Damn. We have to drop the database so we can reload structure.sql:
$ RAILS_ENV=test rake db:drop
$ RAILS_ENV=test rake db:create

# load structure.sql instead of schema.rb:
$ RAILS_ENV=test rake db:structure:load

# Not fixed:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function round_half_down(numeric) does not exist

$ RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=20160421184708
== 20171002190107 CreateRoundHalfDownFunction: reverting ======================
-- execute("DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS round_half_down(numeric)")
   -> 0.0004s
== 20171002190107 CreateRoundHalfDownFunction: reverted (0.0005s) =============

== 20171002190107 CreateRoundHalfDownFunction: migrating ======================
-- execute("CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ROUND_HALF_DOWN(NUMERIC)\n  RETURNS NUMERIC LANGUAGE SQL AS\n$FUNC$\n  SELECT CASE WHEN ($1%1) < 0.6 THEN FLOOR($1) ELSE CEIL($1) END;\n$FUNC$\n")
   -> 0.0014s
== 20171002190107 CreateRoundHalfDownFunction: migrated (0.0014s) =============
```

Now it is fixed!

Yes, I verified that the function is present in structure.sql:

```
--
-- Name: round_half_down(numeric); Type: FUNCTION; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

CREATE FUNCTION round_half_down(numeric) RETURNS numeric
    LANGUAGE sql
    AS $_$
  SELECT CASE WHEN ($1%1) < 0.6 THEN FLOOR($1) ELSE CEIL($1) END;
$_$;
```

Answer (score 3):

For the record, this stopped happening to me with newer versions of the **pg** gem and **PostgreSQL** itself. I also added `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql` to application.rb, because my application makes heavy use of Postgres-specific features, and a number of stored functions.